# Do I have too many cases when implementing circular linked list in c

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm implementing circular linked list in C of which the central part is the `add2list()` function which adds nodes based on the `int data` field in ascending order. I have 5 different scenarios of when to add the node in the function which makes me think that it's kind of too much. Most of the implementations I've seen in google have 2 or 3 cases. However most of those implementations also use multiple functions for adding a node (separate function for adding a node to the beginning/end of the list). I would appreciate your feedback whether I have cases that can be merged (for example case 2 and 4 are quite similar). I added `printList()` function if you would like to print the list.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node * ptr;
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    ptr next;
}item;

void add2list(ptr *head, int num);
void printList(ptr p);

int main() {
    ptr head = NULL;

    add2list(&head, 1);
    add2list(&head, 2);
    add2list(&head, 5);
    add2list(&head, 3);
    add2list(&head, 0);
    add2list(&head, 4);
    add2list(&head, -2);
    printList(head);

    return 0;
}


void add2list(ptr *head, int num) {
    ptr p1, p2, t;

    t = (ptr) malloc(sizeof(item));

    if(!t) {
        printf("not enough memory\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    t -> data = num;
    p1 = *head;

    while(p1 != NULL && p1 -> next != *head && p1 -> data < num) {
        p2 = p1;
        p1 = p1 -> next;
    }

    if(!p1) { 
        //case 1 - if the list is empty
        *head = t;
        t -> next = *head;
    } else if(p1 == *head) {
        if(p1 -> data < t -> data) {
            //case 2 - if we need to add a node to the end of the list if there was only one node before
            (*head) -> next = t;
            t -> next = *head;
        } else {
            //case 3 - if we need to add a node to the beginning of the list
            while(p1 -> next != *head) {
                p1 = p1 -> next;
            }
            p1 -> next = t;
            t -> next = *head;
            *head = t;
        }
    } else if(p1 -> data < t -> data){
        //case 4 - need to add a node at the end of the list if there's more than one node
        p1 -> next = t;
        t -> next = *head;
    } else {
        //case 5 - need to add a node in the middle
        p2 -> next = t;
        t -> next = p1;
    }
}

void printList(ptr head) {
    ptr tmp;

    tmp = head;
    while(tmp -> next != head) {
        printf("%d ->\n", tmp -> data);
        tmp = tmp -> next;
    }
    printf("%d ->\n", tmp -> data);
}
```

Comment: Don't hide pointers behind typedefs, please. :-(

Comment: Don't [cast `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Error messages should go to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

Comment: You should exit with `EXIT_FAILURE` on error, not `0` or `EXIT_SUCCESS`.

Comment: Yes, you have too many cases. There are a few corner cases you have to solve (with pencil&paper) first: cvyclic linked lists are a bad idea... And: 1) you need to manage the head pointer (it could need to be changed by an insertion) 2) an empty list is also a valid list. 3) a one-membered list is also a valid list. 4) a cyclical linked list *cannot* be ordered; there should *at least* be one pair of nodes where the ordering is violated (unless all the nodes have the same value). 5) for() loops are your friend 6) good luck!

Comment: @wildplasser why circular list cannot be ordered? I think it is in my example starting from the head. Also what do you  mean by managing the head pointer?

Comment: I think you can get by with 3 cases. I'll try to write it up as an answer.

Comment: BTW it's always a good idea to use a top-down approach, it makes your code cleaner and more maintainable than n long lines of codes. Moreover it makes the functions reusable.

Comment: @ClaudioCortese `item` is a struct as well, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt (warning, code is untested):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

void add2list(Node **proot, int value) {
    Node **pcur;
    Node *new;

    if (!(new = malloc(sizeof *new))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc(%zu): %s\n", sizeof *new, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new->data = value;

    if (!*proot) {
        // case 1: insert into empty list
        new->next = new;
        *proot = new;
        return;
    }

    if ((*proot)->data >= value) {
        // case 2: insert at beginning of list
        pcur = &(*proot)->next;
        while (*pcur != *proot) {
            pcur = &(*pcur)->next;
        }
        new->next = *proot;
        *proot = *pcur = new;
        return;
    }

    // case 3: insert elsewhere
    pcur = &(*proot)->next;
    while (*pcur != *proot && (*pcur)->data < value) {
        pcur = &(*pcur)->next;
    }
    new->next = *pcur;
    *pcur = new;
}
```

The function first allocates a new node and sets its `data` member. This is common to all three cases, as in your code.

Case 1 is insertion into an empty list. This is pretty trivial.

Case 3 is the "normal" case and almost identical to insertion into a non-circular list (the only difference being the test for end-of-list, which involves `NULL` for a non-circular list). (This subsumes your cases 2, 4, 5.)

Case 2 (insertion at the beginning) is where it gets tricky. This case is special because here we have to update two variables, not just one: The variable in the caller, `*proot` (because it has to be updated to the new head of the list), as well as the `next` pointer of the last node in the list (to keep it properly circular). In this case we have an extra loop that walks through the whole list just to find the address of the last `next` pointer in the list (stored in `pcur`). At the end we update `*proot` and `*pcur` together. (This is your case 3.)

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are definitely too many cases. You should avoid situations like these one and use a top-down approach whenever possible.
Doing so your code will be cleaner and more maintainable.
Moreover you can reuse functions whenever you need them and if you find a bug inside a function it's a matter of correcting the function to make everything works fine.